# @ManagedBean and @Transactional - bug in Spring? Workarounds?

Tags: spring, jsf-2, managed-bean, transactional, spring-transactions

I had the following JSF backing bean in my Webapp

```
@ManagedBean
class MyBackingBean implements Serializable {

    private MyHibernateRepository repository;
    ...

    @Transactional 
    public void save() {
        ....
        repository.save(myObject);
    }

}
```

When it gets to the `repository.save` method call - I get the following error

```
no transaction is in progress
```

I've got two questions

1. Is this because of a bug [like this](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5082)?
2. I believe there are two workarounds - are there any others?

2.1 First workaround - using

```
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
  protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
    repository.save(myObject);
  }
});
```

2.2 Second workaround

Create a helper class and annotate that instead.

2.3 (A possible third workaround would be to annotate @Transactional on a method of an inner class This is quite similar to 2.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Spring annotations (I know that `@Transactional` is a Sun standard - but you need an implementation) - Spring uses AOP to annotate to the class to add the transaction handling code. This only works for Spring beans. If your class is a backing bean for JSF - the Mojarra framework won't insert its own transaction handling code to this annotation.

Short answer - `@Transactional` works for beans loaded by Spring. Otherwise you need to find a framework that supports it or assume it won't work.

Comment: That's a thing to be discussed. Apart from technical problems adding `@Transactional` to the `@ManagedBean` itself, we could talk about repercussions of doing that according to the MVC schema. Being JSF a view layer framework, is it ethical to define transactional operations there or should they go in the service layer? Supposing you make JSF action methods `@Transactional` and not the operations on the service, you would need to replicate the `@Transactional` annotation for other possible access layers, such as a web service.